# how to fix my booking because when i send it. It doesn't show any data at mysql and it show echo "failed"

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm setting up my reservation web application and support UTF-8.

I already running PHP 7 and MySQL also Apache 2.In the past i've tried doing registration form and login form and when doing my reservation form seem end up sending echo "failed".

I'm doing php using method object oriented

this is my bookingtest.php

```
<?php
$php_variable = 'string';
// connection
include ('config.php');
ob_start();  
// if button register pressed
if(isset($_POST['book']))
{
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$swimming = $_POST['swimming'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$numbercus= $_POST['numbercus'];
$suits= $_POST['suits'];
$certificate = $_POST['certificate'];
$guide= $_POST['guide'];


//inserting php form to mysql
$sql_book = "INSERT INTO booking (fname, email, phone, country, swim, 
date, num, suits, cert, guide)
VALUES ('$fname', '$email', '$phone', '$country', $swimming, '$date', 
'$numbercus', '$suits', '$certificate', '$guide')";
//result
if ($result_book = $conn->query($sql_book))
{

    sleep(1);
    echo "success";

}
else
{
    echo "Failed ! Please check your details !";


}

}
?>
```

This is my bookinfo.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- header -->
<head>

<title>BOOKING INFORMATION | E-Diving</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Bungee+Outline&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Archivo+Narrow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Patua+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<!-- top bars -->
<ul>
    <li><a href="homepage.php">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>

</ul>
<h1>BOOKING INFORMATION</h1>

<!-- reservation form -->
<form class="field" method="post" action="booktest.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Details: </legend>
        <br>
        Name: <input type="text" name="fname"  placeholder="Full Name">
        <br>
        <br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" 
        placeholder="example@example.com">
        <br>
        <br>
        Phone:<input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="012-3456789">
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Country: <select name="country" required>
                <option name="country">MALAYSIA</option>
                <option name="country">UNITED STATES</option>
                <option name="country">UNITED KINGDOM</option>
            </select> </p>
        <br>
        <p>Do you know Swimming ?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="swimming">YES
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="radio"  name="swimming">NO
        <br>
        <br>
        Choose your Date: <input  type="date" name="date" min="2019-01- 
        01">
        <br>
        <br>
        No. Customers: <input type="number" name="numbercus" min="1" 
        max="100">
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Do you have swimming suits?</p>
        <input type="radio"  name="suits">YES<br><br>
        <input type="radio"  name="suits">NO
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Level of Certificate :</p>
        <input type="radio" name="certificate">Recretional Scuba Diving 
        Certification Levels.<br>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="certificate">Professional Scuba Diving 
        Certification Levels.
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Do you need a guide?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="guide">YES<br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="guide">NO
        <br>
        <br>


        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <br>

    <input type="submit" name="book" value="Continue...">
    </form>
    </body>

    <!-- style -->
    <style>
    h1 {
    font-family: 'Bungee Outline', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #3A506B;
    }

    body {
    height: 110vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Product', sans-serif;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #6B7FD7, #BCEDF6, #EAF8BF, 
    #99DDC8, #F9CFF2, #A9FBD7);
    }

    .field p {
    font-size: 19px;
    }

    .field input[type="radio"],
    .field input[type="text"],
    .field input[type="number"],
    .field input[type="date"] {
     font-size: 14px;}

    fieldset {
    background-color: #A4BAB7;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
    color: #533E2D;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-size: 19px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    : 16px;}

.field {
    margin-right: 10px;}

legend {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
}

.field input[type="submit"] {
    border: 0;
    background: #4C243B;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #07FEDE;
    padding: 14px 60px;
    width: 200px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: 0.6s;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: cornflowerblue;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.field input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #DCD6F7;
    color: #151E3F;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

}



head {
    display: flex;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #EDF7F6;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    font-weight: lighter;

}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #352208;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #FAE8EB;
    color: #1F2041;
}

.active {
    background-color: #CC7E85;
    transition: 1s;
}






</html>
```

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param

Comment: Print out the actual mysql error instead of the neaningless generic error message and you will know what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `execute` instead of `query` and use prepared statement to handle SQL INJECTION.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO booking (fname, email, phone, country, swim, date, num, suits, cert, guide) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$fname, $email, $phone, $country, $swimming, $date, $numbercus, $suits, $certificate, $guide]);
```

Reference: [Insert query using PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert)